# Check if a download URL is reachable in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to check if a URL is reachable, although this URL is direct to an exe download. I want to know if the same principals count when checking if a normal URL is online and reachable, or I have to check something different with a download link?

I need to do this in C#, but I'm not sure where to start because its a download URL.

Comment: Just send a POST request.

Comment: To check if it's "reachable" you'd have to send it a request.  But that doesn't necessarily need to be a GET or POST or whatever would cause the file to be downloaded.  A HEAD request *should* respond with only headers and not the full content, though it's up to the server how to respond and you don't control that.